# Android ListView background colors always showing grey

Tags: android, listview, view, themes

I have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) that I'm populating from a custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). Inside the Adapter (in the [getView(int, View, ViewGroup)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method) I'm setting the background color of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) using [setBackgroundColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29). The problem is that no matter what color I set the background to it always comes out a dark grey. It might also be worth noting that I'm using the Light theme.

**Relevant (simplified) bits of code:**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View av = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
    av.setBackgroundColor(R.color.myRow_red);
    mName = (TextView) av.findViewById(R.id.myRow_name);
    mName.setText("This is a name");
    return av;
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use: 
`setBackgroundResource(R.color.myRow_red)` 
instead of `setBackgroundColor()`. **In your example background color is assigned with the ID** instead of the actual color described in the resources.

Comment: I have a similar situation but I can't use this solution for shapes. I've asked a more a detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820240/android-canvas-drawrect-colour-always-shows-as-grey

Answer (score 6):

You must set the cacheColorHint attribute to the desired background color for your list. This is a required workaround to account for a drawing optimization Android performs on lists.

See here: [link text](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

Comment: That's right, and if you don't need to change your background color dynamically, you can just add android:background="#FF0000" in your my_row.xml layout file.

Comment: midj: that's actually not true in my case, you're just seeing a super-simplified example.

Comment: @fiXedd: so what's your problem then? Didn't deactivating the color cache help?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem where the divider was coming up grey.  I found that the other solutions had no effect, but `android:divider="<drawable,color, or whatever>"` on my `ListView` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You cold always wrap the whole row inside another view and set the background color on that view. This view would be the first (and only) child of the row.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setBackgroundColor(0xFF5DB9FB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

> `av.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myRow_red));`