# My list view displaying darker color of background color

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

My list view as

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_below="@+id/tags_activity_list_empty_msg"
    android:id="@+id/select_names_tags_lv"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingTop="10.5dip"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"    
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

when I run my application list items shows darker color of same as I used in background color of layout. I tried [1](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) and [2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397183/android-listview-background-colors-always-showing-grey) but could not find my solution. I also used `view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);` in getView method but problem is same. What should be the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);` should be `view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)` cause setBackgroundColor take a hex color value as parameter.