# Android canvas drawRect colour always shows as grey?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm creating a custom view on Android, but the rendered colour is always grey no matter how I try to change it.

```
private void init() {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        float density = res.getDisplayMetrics().density;

        mBackgroundWidth = (int)(DEFAULT_WIDTH * density); // default to 20dp
        mPrimaryColor = gaugeColour;
        mPrimaryWidth = (int)(DEFAULT_WIDTH * density);  // default to 20dp

        x_Corner=30*density;
        y_Corner=30*density;

        mRegularTextSize = (int)(mBackgroundWidth * 0.75); //Double the size of the width;

        mRectPaintPrimary = new Paint() {
            {
                setDither(true);
                setStyle(Style.FILL);
                setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
                setAntiAlias(true);
            }
        };
        mRectPaintPrimary.setColor(mPrimaryColor);

//code for text formatting followed

    }
```

And this is the onDraw function

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);// bound our drawable Rect to stay fully within our canvas

        float left=0,top=0,right=mDrawingRect.right,bottom=mDrawingRect.bottom;

        mProgressRect=new RectF(left,top,(mProgressPercent/100)*right,bottom);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(mProgressRect, x_Corner, y_Corner, mRectPaintPrimary);

        //noinspection ResourceType
        String newColor = getResources().getString(mRectPaintPrimary.getColor());
        Log.d(TAG,"Rect colour while drawing is "+newColor);

        String valueString=((int)mProgressPercent)+"%";
        if(mProgressPercent<10)
            valueString="";
        canvas.drawText(valueString,mProgressRect.centerX(),mProgressRect.centerY()*1.5f,mRegularText);

    }
```

My log actually says that programatically the colour has been modified. So I get a message on the lines of

> D/GaugeView: Rect colour while drawing is #ffe64a19

But what I see on the android display is always the same grey...no matter how what I change the colour to be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got my required result by changing

```
    mRectPaintPrimary.setColor(mPrimaryColor);
```

to

```
    mRectPaintPrimary.setColor(getResources().getColor(mPrimaryColor));
```

Or even better

```
    mRectPaintPrimary.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,mPrimaryColor));
```